# Android - Difference between Broadcast Receiver and Service

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I am wondering, what would be the difference between registering broadcast receiver statically in the manifest and starting a service? Both will run even if the app is in the background and it seems to me that receiver is much less complicated to code. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `BroadcastReceiver` is an app component which is used to react to a system-wide, *inter-app* broadcast, such as [`BOOT_COMPLETED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) or [`WIFI_STATE_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION). A `BroadcastReceiver` should not be used to run `AsyncTask`s or perform other such operations; in such cases, it starts a `Service`. Broadcasts are used to *wake up* an app when some other event occurs on the phone. It is analogous to an *interrupt* in a microprocessor or a `SIGNAL` in Linux.

A `Service` is an app component that performs some long-running operation, such as a calculation-intensive computation or a web-service call, without requiring a UI component (or without requiring *user interaction*). A `Service` continues working even when the foreground `Activity` has been dismissed, and ends of its own accord after completing its work.

A `Service` *polls*, while a `BroadcastReceiver` interrupts. The two are different in nature and purpose, and as such are *not* interchangeable.

Comment: Great answer. I would like to clarify that you can run an `AsyncTask` from a `BroadcastReceiver` but it is bad practice.

Comment: The `context` instance that we get in `onReceive()`  is not the same as the `this` of an `Activity` or `Service`. I've noticed this before, and that's why I've never even *tried* running an `AsyncTask` or web-service from a `BroadcastReceiver`. Go ahead and edit the answer as you see fit :)

Comment: That is correct. That is the case because `Activity` and `Service` extend from `Context`, `BroadcastReceiver` does not. And I agree with you, it is an anti-pattern to use an `AsyncTask` inside of a `BroadcastReceiver`. I was just noting that it is not a limitation from the framework.

Comment: You shouldn't run an AsyncTask or thread from a static broadcastreceiver because the process is scheduled to be killed off the second the broadcastreceiver exits. This means the thread could die in the middle of the operation.

Comment: @ZygoteInit  Maybe you can answer this related questions as well :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785346/update-activity-data-from-service-when-its-paused

Comment: @Snake: interesting question. I gave an answer, hope you find it useful.

Comment: clear explanation thanks to you. but what is the life cycle of a broadcast receiver vs service? i.e until user exists the app etc.

Comment: @Vivek: a Service only exists when and as long as the app process is active. A BroadcastReceiver on the other hand is *triggered* by some kind of external unpredictable event, usually a user or OS action from *outside* the app.

Comment: So if we need to run an AsyncTask in a broadcast receiver (such as get data from firebase), can we start a service from the broadcast receiver?