# Update Activity data from service when its paused

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-lifecycle

Lets say I have an activity that has a data object. It updates its gui component based on that object. Now lets say that it is paused ( OnPause is called) but not stopped or destoryed

Meanwhile , a push notification is received ( intentservice is started) and I need to update that object with the push notification object so I gui is updated when the app is resumed.

I thought about sending a broadcast to the activity so it can update its dataobject But I read somewhere that when activity is paused then broadcasts are not received.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hard but correct way to do this is to build your own custom `ContentProvider` for your app and update all data received from web services and push notifications to this `ContentProvider`. When the `Activity` comes back into the foreground, it updates itself with the new data provided by the `ContentProvider`.

It is *hard* because making a custom `ContentProvider` is a lot of work. It is the *correct* way because it is in conformance with the behavior of mobile applications and with the Android architecture: say a user activates a web-service or some computation-intensive task, and then dismisses the app; or say a push notification arrives and requires the app's data to be updated and displayed. In both cases, the app's `Activity`s may no longer be in the foreground, but a `Service` can be used to perform some non-UI operation. Now at the end of that operation, the `Service` makes changes to the data through the `ContentProvider`, and when the user activates the app again, the `Activity`s get their new data from the `ContentProvider`.

To quote the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html):

> Content providers are the standard interface that connects data in one
>   process with code running in another process.

As a developer, you should always assume that the user may invoke an app at any time and dismiss it at any time. Irrespective of whether an `Activity` is in the foreground or not, the app's data needs to be correctly updated and maintained.

Google's own apps use custom `ContentProvider`s. The `Gmail` app in particular makes use of its `ContentProvider` to get new emails when network connectivity is available and display emails offline. The `Facebook`, `WhatsApp` & `Twitter` Android apps also make use of `ContentProvider`s.

Comment: Thank you for giving the correct behaviour . I would appreciate if there is a tutorial you can point me too. ContentProvider seems to me like shared preferences you can call it from service or activity according to your description

Comment: @Snake: nowhere better to start than the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) ... btw see edited answer.

Comment: The OP should also note that the docs state:"You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to share your data with other applications." This is a more complex answer than is required based on the question...

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much treat it as if the Activity was destroyed.  You can't really assume that it *won't* happen once onPause is called.

If the object represents something that's persistent, then simply update the persistent portion of the object and retrieve it when the Activity resumes.  If it represents a state of a Service for example, then bind to the service and update.  If it's a database, then update the database then refresh the Activity onResume.

If it's a temporary object that's only valid through the life of an Activity, then you need to make something persistent that the Activity can check when it resumes.  Something simple like a boolean variable in the "sharepreferences".  In onResume, check for the object, if it exists, then retrieve object, then clear the object.

Comment: I +1 for the breakdown of the situations. In my case the object is only valid during the life time of the activity. I am still not sure in your answer how I can update that temporary object

Answer (score 1):

You should bind to the `Service` when the `Activity` starts. Then in `onResume` you can request updates that may have occurred while the activity was paused.

You may consider passing data to the activity through a callback to update variables in the activity while it is paused, but then you will need to update the UI in `onResume`.

Also consider that when your `Activity` is paused, it may get destroyed and re-created. You don't seem concerned with that scenario based on your question, but I thought it important to explain it. to handle any changes for this scenario, you would need to persist the data for the change. If you are persisting the data, then you don't need to bind to the `Service` you simply need to check the persistent data store in `onResume`.

EDIT:

In your comment you mention an `IntentService` which you cannot "bind" to. You have several options in this case (basically listed in order of preference). First, you can create a `Service` when your activity is created, then have the `IntentService` forward intents to that service. Second, you can have a `Static` variable in your `Activity` to allow the `IntentService` to access a shared data store. As mentioned previously, you can also persist the data (put in `SharedPreferences`, a file or a database. Last, you can use the `Application` class to store references to the data so that while your app is active, you can pass data.

Comment: I can't bind to the service as it is intent service that get spowned upon receive of GCM. the intentservice will be running at some times during the life of the activity

Comment: That is different from a standard Service. I edited my answer.

Comment: +1 for the ordered solution. Static variable is like application class, it is singleton ..right. So not sure why application would be last

Comment: Static variables are like the `Application` class... but it using it has devs trying to use the class in ways that it is not intended or will cause other problems. It's easier for most devs to handle static variable than to dig into the pros and cons of the `Application` class... IMO

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about sending a broadcast to the activity so it can update
>   its dataobject But I read somewhere that when activity is paused then
>   broadcasts are not received.
>
> What should I do in this case?

I think the resource of that information is incorrect, if you declare a receiver in `onCreate` and remove it at `onDestroy` you wont have any problems. What I mean is, first parse the push notification with your service and then send `localBroadcast` to the activity. It is as simple as you thought. then update your GUI at `onRecieve` method of your `reciever`.

Comment: Hmm, it is on stackoverflow. So broadcast is still received when activity is paused?

Comment: yes, `broadcast` is working, you can try it by your own :-). just use for example `SystemClock.sleep(4000);` before sending the broadcast and press the home button after you received the notification so now your activity has stopped and after 4s your UI must be updated. so again launch your activity to check :-).

Comment: you can use `contentProvider` for large structured data but if you just want to show a text I think sending broadcast is easier and is more accurate but if for example you have a large structured set of data for example list of students list of ... that must be shown and use on other part of your app use `database` and `contentProvider` with `loader`

Comment: thanks for the verification of it(plus one). my structure is more complicated but I see your point